# IF function not populating

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am in need of help with the following if function. I moved the `if(isblank)` part of it up further in the condition.

Initially, the formula was this and it worked.

`=IF(O9="TBD", "TBD", IF(G9="New Phase",I9-30, IF(ISBLANK(O9), I9-$P9,O9)))`

Now the new formula is this.

`=IF(O9="TBD", "TBD", IF(ISBLANK(O9), I9-$P9,O9, IF(G9="New Phase",I9-30)))`

When entering the formula the `'` symbol keeps moving into the front of it, so I know that I have it wrong, I just can't figure out what it is. Does anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

[image]

Comment: Your second `IF` actually shows 4 parameters, it should be 3 (or 2). I think the `,O9`  after the I9-$P9 should be moved to be in your last `IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty easy fix.

You had three outcomes for the initial IF.

Below is the corrected formula:

```
 =IF(O9="TBD", "TBD", IF(ISBLANK(O9), I9-$P9, IF(G9="New Phase",I9-30,O9)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
IF(ISBLANK(O9), I9-$P9,O9, IF(G9="New Phase",I9-30))
   1            2      3   4
```

The IF function has at most 3 parameters, but you have
specified 4 of them.